# Dynamic typings based on value in object

Tags: typescript

We have an API response we are looking to improve our typings for, I'll simplify for this example. Say the API returns something like this where there is a value type and an associated value.

**Note:** Unfortunately this is an existing API and we are just trying to work with what it provides in the current shape.

```json
{
  meta: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    valueType: 'cat' | 'bird'
  }
  value: { paws: number } | { wings: number }
}
```

With this response there is actually a direct relationship between the typings `valueType` and `value`. So to try and improve the typing support for the API response I've tried something like this.

```typescript
type MetaType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

type APIResponseType =
  | {
      meta: MetaType & {
        valueType: 'cat';
      };
      value: { paws: number };
    }
  | {
      meta: MetaType & {
        valueType: 'bird';
      };
      value: { wings: number };
    };

const sampleResponse: APIResponseType[] = [
  {
    meta: {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Garfield',
      valueType: 'cat',
    },
    value: { paws: 4 },
  },
  {
    meta: {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Woody',
      valueType: 'bird',
    },
    value: { wings: 2 },
  },
];
```

This works great so far, where the typings ensure the proper shape of the data when statically typed like they are above. If you tried changing the valueType from `cat` to `bird` in the first object, it would result in a type error.

Now the problem comes up when I try to interact with this data in a dynamic way and try to use a type guard.

```typescript
sampleResponse.forEach((animal) => {
  if (animal.meta.valueType === 'cat') {
    console.log(animal.value.paws);
  }
});

// TypeScript see's the type for value as this:
(property) value: { paws: number; } | { wings: number; }
```

So in this case although the typing initially seems to work, it fails to function as expected with type guards which still means we need to do casting.

So is there a way to achieve this functionality through another method of typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript seems to have a hard time narrowing the parent object, from the inner object. I wish there was an elegant way to handle that, but as @kelly points out in their answer, you will probably need type guards here. (This fact is a surprise to me, but it appears to be true.)

But to prevent you having a different function for *every* possible type, you can use a generic function to do the check for you:

```
function checkResponseType<
  T extends APIResponseType['meta']['valueType']
>(
  res: APIResponseType,
  type: T
): res is Extract<APIResponseType, { meta: { valueType: T }}> {
  return res.meta.valueType === type
}
```

Here we take the type to check as `T`. And we [use `Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter down the union to only the matches.

Then usage feels, and looks, pretty nice.

```
sampleResponse.forEach((animal) => {
  if (checkResponseType(animal, 'cat')) {
    console.log(animal.value.paws); // fine
  }
});
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwEMAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUAlgCYBcUAzsAE6EB2A5gNx4F0IC2E5VtjLuAL4C8oSFACCABQCSAJQgUwAezoUIKcWlZQAPlihdE5OIk3QAZAYBuCADYBXDanIByAMYJgrqIIA0ULaO3AZgCADuFOR0DhwARhDUvr46+piG8AgmmeZQVulBTuZucYTUxK7+gfZO5Onh9AxRUDHxicmCeHjuqlSUnGB2EApKvSHS8ooqas6QANoAulAYczo4+AQZxlg6m0RkUK4AjABMAMyufrub7FxuAOII1ABmhBB2FVcbe4WzIR5eS7XfzXX51KBhSLkAAsvi+BBBG3WeyMWR2302JDcpwu8L2LU4-wA6splMQQECMQRfsVDqVypS9oifjUQvVGs0TnCdIiFiJcM8HHR3MBCKooO4ABYQdwAaxG03U5gAPDokFAIAAPYAQOjECiSWQKsbmOauVGuBZmmmoS14AB8AAodNRFOQJsaZuY8WIQkg8ABKciug2EA0AUW11AQIuVHqmJtQAXSqPBNsg5HVgkE9vRBFdwAc1DoUBDADpUWX0+g0BhfXhOrg8BQBkNPeoy89lNRwzHJY7HQg6IQOPYA8tc8iiM8oI6pTL5QmvahB8PR3YAgDvAHx1OCD01MohmW7MoGKuR-Yq6yy5CKAGmFAAPRPqCvOgQHkNh9AA)

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! I appreciate the single function approach instead of needing a collection of functions. In the production environment valueType can be upwards of 30 different values.

Answer (score 0):

Using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), it's possible to narrow down the type yourself:

```
function isCat(data: APIResponseType): data is Extract<APIResponseType, { meta: { valueType: "cat" } }> {
    return data.meta.valueType === "cat";
}

sampleResponse.forEach((animal) => {
  if (isCat(animal)) {
    console.log(animal.value.paws);
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQx4vW)

TS doesn't let you use `paws` because it's not guaranteed that `animal` doesn't change between when you check it and when you use it (TS doesn't do that kind of static analysis).